# Find function defined in integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{4t\sqrt{t(1-t)}}{x-4t}dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, catalan-numbers

How can the function
$$f(x) := \int_{0}^{1} \frac{4t\sqrt{t(1-t)}}{x-4t}dt $$

be calculated for $x>4$?

This integral came out when I'm trying to calculate
$\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{C_{k}}{N^{k}}$ in an integral form.  ($C_{n}$ is the $n$th Catalan number)

Comment: Use [Euler's substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution).

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=\cos^2 y$. Then
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{4t\sqrt{t(1-t)}}{x-4t}dt =\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{4\cos^4y\sin^2y}{x-4\cos^2y}dy.\\
=& \int_0^{\pi/2}
\left(\frac{x^2}8 - \frac{x^2}8 \frac{x-4}{x-4\cos^2y} -\frac x2\sin^2t 
-\frac12\sin^22t \right) dy\\
=& \frac\pi{16}\left( {x^2} - x\sqrt{x(x-4)}-2x-2\right)
\end{align}